# How to integrate OTLP exporter alone with apache skywalking

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector, otlp-grpc

We are using OAP Skywalking framework to perform tracing and other metrics activities. Everything is working fine.

We have a requirement that metrics data has to be expose with OTLP format. Can I use OTLP exporter alone from openTelemetry along with skywalking ?

Your inputs are much appreciated.

Thanks,
Muthu

I am currently exploring the OTLP exporter examples

Comment: I deleted my answer since you are asking about OpenTelemetry for Java, but that was not clear. I think you should update your question/tags to make it clearer, since there are many language implementations of OpenTelemetry.

Answer (score 0):

> We have a requirement that metrics data has to be expose with OTLP format. Can I use OTLP exporter alone from openTelemetry along with skywalking ?

I think currently(10.0-dev), there is no OTLP exporter from skywalking out-of-box. But you could use [exporter of metrics](https://skywalking.apache.org/docs/main/next/en/setup/backend/exporter/) to forward the data to a service(self-built) and convert them into OTLP format.

Meanwhile, usually, if you just want to query the metrics data, such as integrate with Grafana, the PromQL support is there. https://skywalking.apache.org/docs/main/next/en/api/promql-service/